# Different sets of parameters converted/serialized for the same object for different REST methods?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, jersey

Given the example at http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-xml-with-jersey-jaxb/

Is it possible to use the same Customer class with two different REST methods such that I get different Customer parameters converted/serialized for one REST method than the other?

For example, if for the second REST method, I only want to include the Customer name in the XML output and exclude the pin.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` values are always absent in output XML. So you can set `null` value to field, that you don't want see in output
E.g. class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
class Customer {
    @XmlElement  
    String name;

    @XmlElement
    Integer pin;
```

in this example

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setName("value");
customer.setPin(null);
```

in output will give you

```
<customer>
    <name>value</name>
</customer>
```

and

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setName(null);
customer.setPin(12);
```

in output will give you

```
<customer>
    <pin>12</pin>
</customer>
```

Comment: I also found this question afterwards and found it to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107874/jersey-jaxb-use-same-pojo-for-http-post-and-get-but-return-only-a-subset-of-th